# TableView shows under tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a UITableViewController embedded inside a Navigation and TabBar controller. When I set the background image using

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "Background.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
}
```

the table appears under the TabBar that is translucent.

I can't use Insets or anything as the code above just sets background to the tableview.

I need something that sets background to the view and not the table to use Insets.

And the problem can be solve by using UIViewController(with tableView inside it) but I gotta use static cells so that is out of scope.

Comment: Set the tableView constraint to be 0 above the TabBar

Comment: that also restricts my background to the tableview. I want the background behind TabBar too (that's why it is kept translucent, a translucent tabbar with no background = black TabBar)

Comment: Use a container view to embed the table view controller inside a plain view controller. Alternatively, override load view in the table view controller, and create a new view and add the table view as a child.